# ReactJS - setting an inline style equal to a property on state is not working. What's going on?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a FormWarning to display when users input incorrect information, but it seems to have disappeared on me. I'm trying to control whether or not it displays with this.state.formWarning.display - when the validateInputs function runs, if it determines an input is invalid, it should change the value of display from 'none' to 'block'. I'm trying to set the style for the  Component to having a display that matches this.state.formWarning.display, but I am getting an error. Is my belief that you can set the styles for a component inline via an object not correct? Getting bugs regardless. ie

```
export default class FormOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      formOne: {
        shippingAddress: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          address1: '',
          city: '',
          state: '',
          zip: '',
          country: 'US'
        },
        phone: '',
        email: ''
      },
      formWarning: {
        text: '',
        invalidInputID: '',
        display: 'block'
      },
      isSubmitted: false,
      submitting: false
    }
    this.styles = this.props.styles || {}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.state.stepOne && 
nextProps.state.stepOne.formOneResponse) {
  let formOneResponse = nextProps.state.stepOne.formOneResponse
  formOneResponse.status === "delayed" || formOneResponse.status === "success"
    ? this.setState({isSubmitted: true})
    : alert(formOneResponse.errorMessage)

  this.setState(state => ({submitting: false}))
}
 }


validateInputs = (inputs) => {
  let { email, phone, shippingAddress } = inputs,
    shippingKeys = Object.keys(shippingAddress)
    console.log('validate inputs is firing')
    for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(shippingAddress).length; i++) {
      let key = shippingKeys[i], input = shippingAddress[key]
      if(!input) {
        return this.showFormWarning(key)
    }
  }
    if(!phone) return this.showFormWarning('phone')
    if(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) return 
this.showFormWarning('email')
    return true
  }

  showFormWarning = key => {
    clearTimeout(this.warningTimeout)

     console.log('showformwarnign is firing')
    this.setState(state => ({
      formWarning: {
        ...state.formWarning,
        text: 'Please fill out this field',
        invalidInputID: key,
        display: 'block'
      }
    }))

    this.warningTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        formWarning: {
          ...state.formWarning,
          display: 'none'
        }
      }))
    }, 5000)

    return false
  }

  saveInputVal = (event) => {
    let { formOne: tempFormOne } = this.state,
        input = event.currentTarget

      console.log('saveinputvals is firing')
     if(input.name === 'phone' || input.name === 'email') {
      this.setState(state => ({
        formOne: {
          ...state.formOne,
          [input.name]: input.value
        }
      }))
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({
        formOne: {
          ...state.formOne,
          shippingAddress: {
           ...state.formOne.shippingAddress,
            [input.name]: input.value
          }
        }
      }))
    }
  }

  submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if(!this.validateInputs(this.state.formOne)) return
    this.setState(state => ({submitting: true}))
    this.props.saveShippingData(this.state.formOne)
    this.props.stepOneSubmit(this.state.formOne)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isSubmitted) return <Redirect to="/order" />
    let CustomTag = this.props.labels ? 'label' : 'span',
        { inputs, saveInputVal, styles, state } = this,
        { formWarning, submitting } = state,
        { invalidInputID, text, display } = formWarning

     return (
      <div style={this.styles.formWrapper}>
        {
          typeof this.props.headerText === 'string'
            ? ( <h2 style={this.styles.formHeader}>
{this.props.headerText}</h2> )
            : this.props.headerText.map((text) => {
              return <h2 key={text} style={this.styles.formHeader} 
className={'header'+this.props.headerText.indexOf(text)}>{text}</h2>
            })
        }
        <form onSubmit={this.submit} style={this.styles.form}>
          <FormOneInputs inputs={inputs} saveInputVal={saveInputVal} 
CustomTag={CustomTag} styles={styles} />
          <button style={this.styles.button}>{this.props.buttonText}
</button>
        </form>
        <Throbber throbberText='Reserving your order...' showThrobber=
{submitting} />
        <FormWarning style={display: {this.state.formWarning.display}} invalidInputID={invalidInputID} text={text}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set any CSS class. The approach is as follows:

(1) Given a component you want to render or not render depending on a variable

(2) Make a helper method that checks for the condition and returns the actual component if you want it rendered. Otherwise, do nothing (basically returns undefined)

(3) Call that method from wherever you want the component to possibly appear.

**Concrete example:**

```
class FormOne extends React.Component {
  // (...) all other things omitted to focus on the problem at hand

  renderFormWarning() {
    if (formIsInvalid) {
      return <FormWarning ... />;
    }
    // else won't do anything (won't show)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {/* ... */}
      {this.renderFormWarning()}
    );
  }
}
```

In the above example, replace `formIsInvalid` with some statement that will tell you if the form is invalid. Then, if that condition is true, it will return the `FormWarning` component. Otherwise, no form warning will be shown. From the `render()` method, all you need do is call that helper method.